# Parsing XML to HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, rss

Im currently trying to work on parsing xml to html using a template.html ....

Do you guys know whats the best way to do this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <channel>
 <item>
 <title>My Reminder</title>
  <to>John</to>
 <from>Mike</from>
 <heading>Reminder</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
 </channel>
 </item>
```

To make you understand, I'm reading an RSS feed & want to create an html document (with the template) using the information on the xml of the RSS.

What's the simplest/best way to achieve this?

So the final product would be on "../feedPages"

my-reminder.html

```
 ...extra layout of page...
  <div id="parsedInformation">
  <div id="to"><p>John</p></div>
  <div id="from"><p>Mike</p></div>
  <div id="heading"><p>Reminder</p></div>
  <div id="body"><p>Don't Forget Me This Weekend!</p></div>
  </div> <!--- End of parsedInformation -->
  ...extra layout of page
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT ----

If you create a blog on Googles Bloggr you can access your own blogs feed:

```
  http://your_blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
```

change your_blog with your blog's name and you'll see the xml feed,  I can't change  the sheet as its for reading an RSS feed, I want it so everytime there's a new item(new post) element simply create another file with its title.

Thank you for your time and help!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you create a XSL stylesheet.  Then just use DOMDocument and XSLTProcessor to tranform the XML using the stylesheet.  Less than 10 lines of PHP, you just need to build the stylesheet:

Comment: Yes, but there was a PHP tag :-)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast And....that is exactly my question......How do I display, I made a couple of edits so you can understand my situation....